# Autofill with signature in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm IDE, is there any shortcut to autofill a function call with its signature variable names?

My variable names usually match the signature of the function I am calling in my pipeline and it would save me a lot of time to just autofill those particular names.

Screenshot of example using a MWE scratch file:

[image: signature_variables_tantalizingly_close]

Is there a shortcut I can hit at this point that will fill in the signature variables `bar` and `baz` for me to give me `foo(bar, baz)`?

Comment: To have a `less error prone code`, it is better to not re-use the same variables names. It is true that it will depend on the variables scope and lifetime. But if you use some mutable function this can be problematic.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but if you define the arguments as keyword arguments, they will appear as suggestions for each argument and that can save you some time. Still it's two more clicks instead of one so it's not exactly what you mean

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry I meant `functions with mutable data types parameters` e.g. `dictionary`. The problem there occur when the variable gets updated inside the function and the input parameter is not expected to be updated.  Unfortunately I couldn't update my comment!

Comment: Yeah, this would be a nice feature.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Agree but the reuse of the same names induces in confusion when debugging the code when any error occur. Anyway that is off topic here :)